# MS Access VBA Cross tab report legend sort order

Tags: ms-access, vba

The problem is hard to explain ,
I have an access report with a stacked bar chart to show the percentage fills over time like the one in this example  : [Click here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/stacked-column.htm)

The legend for the chart i have is a number followed by the name, for e.g

> 1-Mango
>   2-Apple
>   3-Banana

etc

I want to sort this according to the above format but when i have more than **10 items the 10-Pineapple comes before 1-mango when it should appear after 9-somefruit** .
The underlying query for the access report uses a Cross Tab query in which the items are created as

**Column heading:[PrefixPriorityNumber]&"-"&[FruitName]**

I even used the Sort:Ascending but it still doesnt affect my custom ordering that i wanted to show.

I also tried to google "sorting alpha numeric strings" but this is clearly more than that.Any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are getting a text sort. You need to format the prefix number.

```
 Column heading: Format([PrefixPriorityNumber], "00") & "-" & [FruitName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use another digit, as Remou suggests (01 instead of 1) or start using letters.  A > 9, B > A, etc.